# Passing Django variable to `<div>` tag

Tags: html, django

I want to pass a Django variable to a tag. In my case I would like to pass it to the `<div>` tag.

I want to set the `<div>` tag id with the variables returned by my view.

For example (template):

```
<div class="pool">
        {% for pools in poolID %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ pools }}">
                    {{ pools }}
                </button>
                <div id="{{ pools }}" class="collapse">
                    <div>
                        {% for mem in member %}
                            {{ mem.first_name }}

                            <br>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Although I don't think the problem is in the view, then again:

```
def pool(request):
 poolID = Member.objects.order_by().values_list('pool_id').distinct()
    member = Member.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'app/pool.html', {'poolID':poolID, 'member':member})
```

When I click the button, it should expand the div, but it doesn't. Meaning the variable syntax is wrong (that's my assumption at least).

The first variable that my view returns is: ('test pool id',)

It should be assigned to target of the button (which includes the hash before the variable) and the id of the div.

Any help or direction would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: I added a screen shot. You can see the variable name in the buttons, I'm trying to set those same variable names in the div and button target, but don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: No we need to see the actual HTML. Although it looks like those are single-element tuples for some reason; maybe you should also show the view.

Comment: OK I will add more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values_list` returns a list of lists, even if you're only selecting a single field per item. You should use `flat=True` to get a single list.

```
poolID = Member.objects.order_by().values_list('pool_id', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: WOW, and here I thought the problem was not in view. Thanks Daniel, appreciate it.